# How can I submit an app in Polish to the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to upload an app to the App Store, but there's an issue with the language of the app. While creating the app in iTunes, they are giving me the dropdown with language selection, but there is no option for the Polish language.

Is there a way I can submit an app to iTunes in Polish?

Answer (score 0):

If your wanted language is not in the list, there is **no way** to localize the description for that language.

However, if you want to publish your app **only** in that language, you can select any language you want from the list and it will appear for all App Store customers.

Answer (score 0):

Polish support has been added in June 2018 for both the iOS and macOS app stores: https://9to5mac.com/2018/06/12/apple-support-for-ios-update/